# OSX Operation Not Permitted on Immutable flag

Tags: macos, mac, command-line

Anyone know super command for replacing locked .plist?
I have locked desktop.plist (immutable flags) needs to replace with a new desktop.plist.
Problem is unable to replace the existing .plist. I get error "Operation Not Permitted" It is impossible to apply chflags nouchg to multiple Macs and users. Can anyone help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way around it, you need to unlock the file (e.g. with `chflags nouchg`) first in order to change/replace it. Or, to put it another way, the "super command" you need is:

```
super_cp() {
    chflags nouchg "$2"    # Unlock the file to allow replacement
    cp "$1" "$2"           # Replace the file
    chflags uchg "$2"      # Relock the replacement
}

super_cp newdesktop.plist desktop.plist
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this to unlock files via ARD first
find . -name 'com.apple.desktop.plist' -exec chflags nouchg {} \;

it worked. I will try the 'super command'

Comment: Note that you won't be able to use a shell function (like `super_cp`) in a `find -exec` clause, since that's executed directly by find rather than via the shell. But I think you could use something like `find ... -exec chflags nouchg {} \; -exec cp newdesktop.plist {} \; -exec chflags uchg {} \;`

Comment: I have executable script that runs on local macs. This is a part of it

    >TARGET_FILE=/Volumes/Deploy/com.apple.desktop.plist
    >ls /Volumes/Data/UsersHomeAD | while read ACC
    do
    >echo "Processing : "$ACC
    >if [ -d /Volumes/Data/UsersHomeAD/$ACC/Desktop ]; then
    >cp -f $TARGET_FILE /Volumes/Data/UsersHomeAD/
        $ACC/Library/Preferences'
    >echo "Complete"